# Google wants sites to use SSL, but complains when compression is turned off to prevent BREACH hacks

Tags: seo, https, security

Google has let it be known that they want websites to move to SSL, and they will start making it more and more clear that HTTP sites are 'insecure'. But then using their [PageSpeed tool](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), they will mark you down if your site [does not have compression enabled](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/EnableCompression).

The problem is that it does not seem to be possible to enable SSL and compression at the same time thanks to the [BREACH vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH).

In terms of Google and SEO, is it more important to have SSL, or compression? Or should I not worry about BREACH and go ahead and enable SSL And compression?

Comment: Interesting.  I hadn't heard of this attack.   The Wikipedia article you link to does a very poor job explaining it.  I found this article much better: https://arstechnica.com/security/2013/08/gone-in-30-seconds-new-attack-plucks-secrets-from-https-protected-pages/

Answer (score 2):

Google is pushing SSL for a reason that web experience should be safe.

A vast number of websites already moved to HTTPS.

With regards breach vulnerability or general issue of any kind, i am sure Google is well aware and they update using webmasters blog.

With regards to compression, if your website process highly sensitive data then you may take required action, more info here:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20216/should-i-disable-ssl-compression-because-of-crime

If the website is general then it shouldn't matter.

Also, note that Google is pushing with a ranking factor, so it's good to have it.

Comment: "i am sure Google is well aware and they update using webmasters blog" - Has Google published anything on this specific issue (HTTPS + compression)?